# How to make CIRCOS plot of VCF file?

Tags: vcf, snp, circos

I have 3 VCF files, I want to make CIRCOS plot just like the following:

https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-020-70527-8/figures/4

I try to follow the [tutorial](http://circos.ca/documentation/tutorials/2d_tracks/tiles/images) but could not understand. The genome is of Zea mays and the reference files used in making VCF files are downloaded from [Ensembl plant](ftp://ftp.ensemblgenomes.org/pub/plants/release-50/fasta/zea_mays/dna/Zea_mays.B73_RefGen_v4.dna.toplevel.fa.gz). How I can make karyotype and config files?